# Unable to initialize kubeadm?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

Getting error while initializing kubeadm.

$: - `sudo kubeadm init`

```
 [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.25.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: missing optional cgroups: blkio
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-ipv4-ip_forward]: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward contents are not set to 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72504257/i-encountered-when-executing-kubeadm-init-error-issue) and [here](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/4581) and followed the steps but unable to resolve.

To resolve I did ,
FIRST :

```
sudo rm /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo systemctl restart containerd
kubeadm init
```

SECOND: I have edited config.toml file and changed  `systemd_cgroup = true`

Then I tried

```
sudo kubeadm init --v=5



I0824 10:32:04.093515   27017 initconfiguration.go:116] detected and using CRI socket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
I0824 10:32:04.093872   27017 interface.go:432] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I0824 10:32:04.093890   27017 interface.go:437] Default route transits interface "eth0"
I0824 10:32:04.094018   27017 interface.go:209] Interface eth0 is up
I0824 10:32:04.094084   27017 interface.go:257] Interface "eth0" has 2 addresses :[172.31.37.138/20 fe80::69:d1ff:fea7:79ae/64].
I0824 10:32:04.094113   27017 interface.go:224] Checking addr  172.31.37.138/20.
I0824 10:32:04.094131   27017 interface.go:231] IP found 172.31.37.138
I0824 10:32:04.094147   27017 interface.go:263] Found valid IPv4 address 172.31.37.138 for interface "eth0".
I0824 10:32:04.094162   27017 interface.go:443] Found active IP 172.31.37.138
I0824 10:32:04.094197   27017 kubelet.go:196] the value of KubeletConfiguration.cgroupDriver is empty; setting it to "systemd"
I0824 10:32:04.098681   27017 version.go:187] fetching Kubernetes version from URL: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.25.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
I0824 10:32:04.770260   27017 checks.go:568] validating Kubernetes and kubeadm version
I0824 10:32:04.770328   27017 checks.go:168] validating if the firewall is enabled and active
I0824 10:32:04.779958   27017 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 6443
I0824 10:32:04.780157   27017 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 10259
I0824 10:32:04.780197   27017 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 10257
I0824 10:32:04.780232   27017 checks.go:280] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
I0824 10:32:04.780251   27017 checks.go:280] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
I0824 10:32:04.780265   27017 checks.go:280] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
I0824 10:32:04.780278   27017 checks.go:280] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml
I0824 10:32:04.780293   27017 checks.go:430] validating if the connectivity type is via proxy or direct
I0824 10:32:04.780317   27017 checks.go:469] validating http connectivity to first IP address in the CIDR
I0824 10:32:04.780341   27017 checks.go:469] validating http connectivity to first IP address in the CIDR
I0824 10:32:04.780353   27017 checks.go:104] validating the container runtime
I0824 10:32:04.794206   27017 checks.go:329] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
I0824 10:32:04.794285   27017 checks.go:329] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
I0824 10:32:04.794384   27017 checks.go:644] validating whether swap is enabled or not
I0824 10:32:04.794436   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable crictl
I0824 10:32:04.794466   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable conntrack
I0824 10:32:04.794486   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable ip
I0824 10:32:04.794506   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable iptables
I0824 10:32:04.794530   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable mount
I0824 10:32:04.794552   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable nsenter
I0824 10:32:04.794571   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable ebtables
I0824 10:32:04.794591   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable ethtool
I0824 10:32:04.794608   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable socat
I0824 10:32:04.794629   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable tc
I0824 10:32:04.794646   27017 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable touch
I0824 10:32:04.794666   27017 checks.go:516] running all checks
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: missing optional cgroups: blkio
I0824 10:32:04.808265   27017 checks.go:401] checking whether the given node name is valid and reachable using net.LookupHost
I0824 10:32:04.808291   27017 checks.go:610] validating kubelet version
I0824 10:32:04.871023   27017 checks.go:130] validating if the "kubelet" service is enabled and active
I0824 10:32:04.906852   27017 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 10250
I0824 10:32:04.907135   27017 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 2379
I0824 10:32:04.907346   27017 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 2380
I0824 10:32:04.907542   27017 checks.go:243] validating the existence and emptiness of directory /var/lib/etcd
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-ipv4-ip_forward]: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward contents are not set to 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
error execution phase preflight
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:235
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:421
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:154
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
        cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
        cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594
```

Getting error message:

```
service kubelet status



kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-08-24 14:56:42 UTC; 6s ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
    Process: 2561 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2561 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Comment: I mean, the error message is clear and descriptive: “/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward contents are not set to 1” Have you taken steps to resolve this error?

Comment: I don't know how to set that. Trying to learn kuberfnates, not having much hands on to linux.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure kubernetes can do IPv4 forwarding. This is assuming you use `iptables` and not `ipvs`.
Run the following script to add bridge (for IPv4 and IPv6 and IP forwarding):

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward                 = 1
EOF
```

Also, make you have swap turned off, overlay network and bridge netfilter turned on, like:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf
overlay
br_netfilter
EOF

sudo modprobe overlay
sudo modprobe br_netfilter

# immediately turn off swap - until reboot
sudo swapoff -a
# turn off swap after restart
sudo sed -i 's|^/swap.img|#/swap.img|g' /etc/fstab

# reboot sysctl
sudo sysctl --system
```

Answer (score 0):

Open # nano /etc/containerd/config.toml

Do Comment # disabled_plugins = ["cri"]

then, Do sudo systemctl restart containerd

then execute kubeadm init